# Dynamic div append on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, dynamic, append

On a website on iPhone i've made, it seems that the iPhone can't handle content with dynamic height. The footer div isn't pushed down by the contents thats being appended in a div preceeding the footer. Then the footer and the new content ends up "overlaying" each other, with the content from the dynamic div just appearing as its overflowing.

Any way to fix this..? (Cant reproduse it in chromes iPhone emulator)

Edit, here is the code that appends:

```
$("#wrapper").empty();
$.each(full_playlist, function(j, current_song){
    if(!current_song.now_playing){ //check that the song isnt playing
        $("#wrapper").append(List.generateSong(current_song, false, true));
    }
});
```

Edit, CSS for footer and wrapper:

```
footer{
    margin-top:0px !important;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 113%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-right: 5vh;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: For sure, iOs can handle dynamic content. Please show some code.

Comment: Edited post with the code that appends now. The List.generateSong only returnes html that is to be appended

Comment: Show the css of the footer and the container you use for appending.

Comment: Added CSS for the footer and wrapper also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding height: auto; fixed it the issue